# Human detection is not uniform

Tags: python, video, opencv

I am doing a people counter activity on a live video using Raspberry pi 3 model B with PiCamera.
Following is our code :

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from threading import Thread

from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
resX = 240
resY = 180
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (resX,resY)
camera.framerate = 10
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(resX, resY))

# initialize textIn and textOut values
textIn = 0
textOut = 0

print(time.strftime("%H_%M_%S"))
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(time.strftime("%H_%M_%S")+'.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (resX, resY))

# initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
detectFlag = 0
detectCounter = [0]
# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

# methods for IN and OUT counters
def testIntersectionIn(x, y, z):

    if((x >= 75) and  (x <= 90) and (x < z[0]) and (z[0]>0)):
        print (x,z[0],"IN")
        return True
    return False

def testIntersectionOut(x, y, z):

    if((x >= 75) and  (x <= 90) and (x > z[0]) and (z[0]>0)):
        print (x,z[0],"OUT")
        return True

    return False

previousObj = (0,0)

def classfier(testImage,threadNum,capTime, detectCounter):
    global textIn, textOut, previousObj
    #print(threadNum,capTime)
    (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(testImage, winStride=(8, 8),
        padding=(16, 16), scale=1.1)

    rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
    pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)

    # draw the final bounding boxes

    cv2.line(image, (75,0), (75,192), (250, 0, 1), 2) #blue line
    cv2.line(image, (90,0), (90,192), (0, 0, 255), 2)#red line

    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:

        print("Image detected")
    print ("Previous Coord : ",previousObj)
        detectCounter[0] = 0
        cv2.rectangle(testImage, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    rectangleCenterPont = ((xA + xB) /2, (yA + yB) /2 )
    cv2.circle(testImage, rectangleCenterPont, 1, (0,0,255), 5)
    print (rectangleCenterPont)

    if(testIntersectionIn((xA + xB) /2, (yA + yB) /2,previousObj)):
            textIn += 1
                #print testIntersectionIn((x + x + w) / 2, (y + y + h) / 2)

        if(testIntersectionOut((xA + xB) /2, (yA + yB) /2,previousObj)):
            textOut += 1
                #print textOut

    previousObj = rectangleCenterPont


    cv2.putText(image, "In: {}".format(str(textIn)), (10, 50),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, "Out: {}".format(str(textOut)), (10, 70),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # print(pick,"\n");
    curTime = time.time()
    #print ("Total time from capture", curTime - capTime)
    out.write(testImage)
    cv2.imshow("After NMS", testImage)

# capture frames from the camera
i = 0
frameCount = 0
prevTime = time.time()
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    if (detectCounter[0] < 10):
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
        print ("Waiting ", detectCounter[0])
        detectCounter[0] += 1
    else:
        GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)
    image = frame.array
    captureTime = time.time()
    # print("FRAME Time", captureTime-prevTime)
    prevTime = captureTime

    # if frameCount == 0:
        # frameCount = 0
    #if i == 0:
    t1 = Thread(target = classfier, args = (image,i,captureTime,detectCounter))
    t1.start()
    threadPick = t1.join()


    # cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

     # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        cleanup_stop_thread();
        sys.exit()
        t1.stop()

        break
```

In the above code

- We draw two lines on the frame
- Finding the center point of rectangle
- When that center point falls between these two lines we increase our
  counter
- IN and OUT counter logic is based on the values from these two lines

**The Problem I face** here is

The rectangle over the human is not on it uniformly. It disappears and appearing again at random points in the frame. 
For e.g, When the object comes close to the first line the rectangle disappears and comes again when he goes out of the line. So here the center point of rectangle will not fall between these lines so our counter will not increase for this case.
In some cases the detection is happening late. Not once the person comes into the frame.

Please suggest me any ways to avoid this and maintain that rectangle all the time when any person is in the frame.

Comment: @DarthVader Okay. Is there a way to transfer this question directly to SO without me copy paste manually?

Comment: Yes, I'll migrate it for you.